# Custom shortcode not displaying categories and correct date

Tags: wp-query, shortcode

I wrote a short code to work with an event plugin (the plugin creates the custom post type of event). I want to pull all future events from the database that use a specific category and list them on the page in order of the event date. The events are showing up but the category selection is not working and it is also showing past events.

Here is my shortcode:

```
/* Exhibitions Shortcode */
add_shortcode( 'event_list', 'eventList' );
function eventList( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'tax' => '',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'date_query' => array(
        array(
        'column' => 'event_start_date',
        'after' => date('F j, Y'),
        ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => '',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'event_start_date',
    ) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="eventListing">
    <div class="column oneThird">
           <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="column twoThird last">
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
           <?php echo get_the_content( $more_link_text, $stripteaser ); ?>
            </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
    }
}
/* END Exhibitons */
```

the shortcode in use is [event_list tax="exhibitions" posts_per_page="3"]

UPDATED CODE With Categories working:

```
/* Exhibitions Shortcode */
add_shortcode( 'event_list', 'eventList' );
function eventList( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'event-categories',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $atts['tax'],
            ),  
        ),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'date_query' => array(
            'after' => date('F j, Y'),
            'column' => 'event_start_date',
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => $atts['posts_per_page'],
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'event_start_date',
    ) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="eventListing">
    <div class="column oneThird">
           <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="column twoThird last">
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
           <?php echo get_the_content( $more_link_text, $stripteaser ); ?>
            </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
    }
}
/* END Exhibitons */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by looking at your code I see a few places I'd investigate.

1) I don't see any use of the $atts that come through the shortcode. Specifically the 'tax' and 'post_per_page' attributes.

So try changing this;

```
'tax' => '',
```

to this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => '$atts['tax']',
    ),
),
```

And same with the empty posts_per_page:

```
'posts_per_page' => '$atts['posts_per_page']',
```

Looks liek you got issue 1 fixed. Good job. :)

2) To fix the date issue we probably need to know how the custom field created by the events plugin is storing the event date.

EDIT: Yep. So it appears the plugin that created the custom post types also created a custom DB table. and if you are to get the event_start_date you'll need to refer to that custom table.

Comment: Sadly this did not fix the issue. The Time sort is "working" but isn't searching the event_start_date instead it is pulling from the publish date. and Category filter just isn't working at all...

Comment: I also discovered that {tax} (string) was depreciated in wordpress so now I need to use something like this,
`array(
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'tax_query' => array(
  array(
   'taxonomy' => 'people',
   'field'    => 'slug',
   'terms'    => 'bob',
  ),
 ),
);`

Comment: Ahh yes, ok.  So how about the post_per_page? is that working? You only get 3 posts? ... I'll update my answer with proper taxonomy array.

Comment: Hey Sean I added the new code in the question above so it is what I have now. The limiter is work the only thing that I have left to fix is to only allow posts that are for future events to be shown. The database column is the event_start_date column. But no matter what I put there it only filters by publish date.

Comment: Looks like you'll want to use meta_key or meta_query rather than the date_query. See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: The date is being stored in a new table called wp_em_events 
The table then has the post_id to associate it with the original post as well as a column called event_start_date here is an image of the table structure http://i.imgur.com/YSGc65Y.png

Comment: Would it be possible to use the meta_query to actually filter out past events or would it simply return the start date into the query. Is meta_compair the answer?

Comment: Actually I think you'll need to specify the different table when pulling from the DB. Check out this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb and CTRL+F for tables. the meta_query isn't going to cut it.
You might be helped out a bit if you check out the code in the plugin that created this table and see if there is any useful code in there already written.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep working on it with wpdb... in the mean time I am going to use a post expression plugin to expire the posts at a certain date/time this will remove the 'publish' status which in turn will remove it from the list but it will be nive to have this automatically do this in the future. Big thanks Sean, you have really helped me out!

Comment: p.s. it's funny because it will let me sort by event_start_date but won't let me filter :/

Comment: You are very welcome. Sorry we couldn't get this to work exactly how you wanted, and I'm glad you found a way. 

So is the way when working with other people's plugins and themes. :)

Answer (score 0):

this will work with an theme but a couple things to note, the code is looking for a custom post type of 'event' and it is sorting the order of the events by 'event_start_date' if you were to change those to match whatever plugin you are using you could totally use it! you could also add those as attributes in the the shortcode itself but i am not a huge fan of super long shortcodes myself.